# passing yes argument while scp command

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, scp

I am facing an issue when I run simply these commands.

The remote server want to pass `yes` to add the key in RSA file because first time connection established with `scp`.

commands are given below

```
#!/bin/bash

scp  -P58222 root@IP:/root/K /N
/usr/bin/expect -c 'expect "\n" { expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" }'
send "yes\r"
expect "$ "
send "exit\r"
```

Actually I have to pass yes in my script while asking

The authenticity of host 'ip address (ip address)' can't be established.

```
RSA key fingerprint is xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

how can I get rid of this problem?

with

```
scp -o  StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

it is still asking.

Comment: You can just pass arguments to ssh/scp to tell it not to ask the question; no need to use `expect` to script the answer.

Comment: That said -- which *specific* question are you telling it to auto-answer yes to? If it's an unknown-host-key question, for instance, that would help.

Comment: specifically, `scp -q` enables quiet mode, which doesn't need to ask for confirmation.

Answer (score 35):

```
scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@IP:/root/K
```

Obviously, this isn't a very secure solution. Works for one-shots where you're not concerned about man in the middle, though.

Comment: Actually,
when connection established it show

connection can't established because remote host info not added
when we type yes it display host machine info  added successfully.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at `man scp` under the `-o` option for a full list of ssh/scp options. Depending on your setup, you may need another option flag set.

Comment: I am checking it is helpful but now testing ..!!

Comment: The authenticity of host 'ip address (ip address)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? 
it is still asking that

Comment: Try redirecting the known hosts file to /dev/null: `scp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`...

Answer (score 10):

Probably the best way to do this would be to use the following command before your scp command:

`ssh-keyscan -H ${SSH_HOST} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

This will add the SSH_HOST to your known hosts and `scp` will not complain. Substitute ${SSH_HOST} for the IP address you are trying to connect to.

Comment: This should be accepted answer because we aren't disabling any security features...

Comment: It solved my problem.

Answer (score 9):

For me, this works:

```
 yes | scp -r /opt/MyFiles root@<MyNewServerIP>:/opt/MyFiles
```

Regards. =)